# Is there anything wrong with AsyncTask?

Tags: android

```
@Override 
protected InputStream doInBackground(String... url){                
    try {
        InputStream stream = downloadXml(url[0]);
        new ParseXml(stream); //for testing porpuses: outputs ok to logcat
        return stream;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("dbg","exception");   
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }   
}

@Override 
protected void onPostExecute(InputStream result) {
    if (result != null) {    
       new ParseXml(result); //crashes the app                  
    }
    Log.d("dbg","postexecute triggered ok");        
}
```

Code is pretty self explanatory i think, i tried changing the passing type to just Object and type casted it where needed but it didn't worked either.

Is there anything undocumented in sdk that i should know of ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

obviously, Crash.. You are doing lengthy (also may be network related) operation in **MainUI Thread**. as `onPostExecute()` of **AsyncTask** runs on In MainUI Thread only. So always keep it in `doInBackground()`.

This code line `new ParseXml(result);`  should be in `doInBackground()` of **AsyncTask**.

**Update:**

So complete the Parsing of XML in `doInBackground()` and only pass the result in `onPostExecute()` if only you want to reflect the updation on Application UI.

Comment: But i need it in postexecute so i return can use the result on MainUI.